# filter list of items symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig, entitymanager, symfony-routing

I am building a web application where a user make a post. the post includes category and location. i can view posts for the categories and locations seprately.

What i am trying to do is to filter the view to list only category list from a location. for example when i click on shoe category i want to filter to show only USA location leaving the other locations. Thanks

Controller:

```
  public function catergoryitemsAction($name)
  {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $category = $em->getRepository('KaftanAvenueBundle:Category')->find($name);

    return $this->render('@KaftanAvenue/Page/categoryitems.html.twig',
        ['category' => $category]);

}


public function locationitemsAction($name)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $location = $em->getRepository('KaftanAvenueBundle:State')->find($name);

    return $this->render('@KaftanAvenue/Page/locationitems.html.twig',
        ['location' => $location]);

}
```

routing:

```
categoryitems:
     path:    /category/{name}
     defaults: {_controller: KaftanAvenueBundle:Page:catergoryitems}


locationitems:
    path:    /location/{name}
    defaults: {_controller: KaftanAvenueBundle:Page:locationitems}
```

twig:

```
 {% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

 {% block body %}
   <div class="container">
       {{ category.name }}
    <div class="row">
        {% for entry in category.ads %}
            <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                    <img src="{{ asset('images/'~ entry.imageName )  }}" class="media-object" style="width:100px">
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading" ><a style="color: #550000" href="{{ path('view',{id : entry.id}) }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h4>
                    <p>Price:  {{ entry.price }}
                        <br>
                        Created: {{ entry.timestamp | date('d/m/y') }}
                        <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

 {% endblock %}
```

index.html.twig

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

 {% block body %}

<header class="page-heading">

    <div class="container">


    </div>
</header>


<div class="container marketing">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
           <a href="{{ path('categoryitems',{ 'name' : category.id}) }} "> <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h4>Cap</h4></a>

        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->

    </div>

    </div>
```

{% endblock %}

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:

```
$category = $em->getRepository('KaftanAvenueBundle:Category')->find($name);
```

Why would you stop in such a good path and give the category instead of posts related to that category to your view?

I'd replace by something like:

```
$category = $em->getRepository('KaftanAvenueBundle:Category')->findOneByName($name);

$posts = $em->getRepository('KaftanAvenueBundle:Post')->findByCategory($category);

return $this->render('@KaftanAvenue/Page/categoryitems.html.twig',
        ['posts' => $posts]);
```

Please note that I don't know either your Category nor Post entities, so it might be a bit different but the idea is here.